Why do I need to clean flash between different Android versions on custom ROMs but not on OEM updates?
When flashing custom ROMs, I've noticed that it's recommended to perform a clean flash (i.e., wipe the device's data, cache, and system partitions) when upgrading between different Android versions (e.g., from 12 to 13). However, this isn't the case for OEM updates, where I can seamlessly update from one version to another without performing a clean flash. What are the technical reasons behind this difference? Why is a clean flash required for custom ROMs but not for OEM updates?

As you already wrote, it is only "recommended to perform a clean flash" - not necessary.
The reason for this recommendation is simple: Custom ROM authors usually own only one or two devices of that model they develop the custom ROM for. Therefore, testing a ROM update without data reset is a task the ROM developers usually don't test very often, as it requires quite a bit of time and preparation.
Compare to a device manufacturer which usually has device farms with dozen or even hundred of phones of that model for testing updates before they are released. Otherwise, a released update that causes problems (like the defect Samsung updates for S10/Note 10/M51) may result in a lot of work for the manufacturer's support crew, and of course a lot of angry customers, which means a loss of reputation.
In the end, you can break it down to money. The device manufacturer has enough money to perform large scale tests to be sure nothing goes wrong when applying an OTA update. On the other hand, custom ROM developers don't have much money and time or a large set of test devices to test different update scenarios. Therefore, they recommend to clear data - this way, the developers don't even have to consider update scenarios which saves them time they can spend on developing new features or debug existing problems on the ROM they maintain.

Plus writing the code for "I found something weird from a previous release, now fix it" is additional work, even if you already know that the issue is potentially there. Good release engineering means covering all the bases, but hobbyists just don't have the resources for good releng most of the time. Even the pros aren't exactly 100% :)
